# How to refresh tkinter window if requirements aren't fulfilled when pushing button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So I have a make story button, but I want it to be so if the entry boxes are empty or an adjective is not selected, it refreshes the window and does not make the story(continue on with code). I have tried using self.destory() and self.update(), but each time it says it is missing a positional argument 'self'. ANd then once I change it to self.destroy.(self), it says GUI has no attribute 'children"(like what lol)

Here is my code for the make story and refresh method (all of this is in a GUI class which I did not include here since it would take too much space)(my main window tho is called self.main_window)

```
 def refresh(self):
    self.main_window.destroy(self)
    self.__init__()
    
  def make_story(self):
    '''makes the story'''
  #gets the entrys 
    person = self.person_entry.get()
    
    # selctets body part based on raido button selected
    bodypart = ""
    if self.radio_var.get() == 1:
      bodypart = 'forehead'

    if self.cb_var1.get() == 1:
      adjective1 = "silly"

    if person.strip()  =="" or  self.cb_var1.get()  == 0:
      tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error', "Please make sure all entry boxes are filled and at least one adjective is selected")
      self.refresh()
    else:
       pass
        
    text_box = Text(self.eight_frame, height = 10, width = 52, bg = "pink")
    story = "The famous singer " + person 
    text_box.insert(INSERT,story)

    text_box.pack()
```